# csvsql in csvkit library is missing packages how to fix?

Tags: python-3.6, csvkit

I need to generate a postgresql schema via a csv. I have found the `csvkit` library with the `csvsql` functionality.

When I run the following command from docs, with my csv:

```
csvsql -i postgresql examples/realdata/FY09_EDU_Recipients_by_State.csv
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportWarning: Not importing directory /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits: missing __init__
```

according to user `chbrown` here(https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9823/) I need to install another library, but I am not sure how to even run the commands they have posted.

How would I fix this error message to produce my postgres schema?

I am open to any library to help me generate the schema. 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an empty '**init**.py' file. Paste into the file path to the package `mpl_toolkits`